# Occasionally a record is missing from PHP/JSON array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am calling a PHP script to get results, and then turning the array to a javascript array. My array is for a multiple choice quiz, there can be 2 to 6 answers, it pulls the question with the answer.

I've been doing alot of testing, and sometimes a record is missing when it is expected. For example, after pulling the next question which should have 5 answers, only 4 answers are pulled. Even if I reload the quiz, the same result is missing.

This is seemingly random, there is no pattern as to when this problem occurs, for example, the first test found the first question which has six answers was missing an answer result. Another test found the third question which was a four answer question was missing an answer result.

I used the Javascript console, and the only pattern I could identify when one of these questions has a result missing, it is always the answerid which would be the first, ie if the answerids are 285, 286, 287, then 285 would be the missing one.

Out of 25 tested questions, only 3 have a result missing.

Here is my code, the PHP script...

```
$thisquizid = $_REQUEST['quizidvalue'];
$questionquery = pg_query($db_handle, "SELECT * FROM question LEFT JOIN answer USING (questionid) WHERE quizid = '$thisquizid'");
$questionrows = pg_num_rows($questionquery); 
$questionresult = pg_fetch_array($questionquery); 

$questions = array();

while($row = pg_fetch_array($questionquery)) {
    $questions[$row['questionid']][] = $row;
}
die(json_encode($questions));
```

And my Javascript

```
var questions;
var currentquestion = 0;


$(document).ready(function(){

        console.debug("in ajax");
        jQuery.ajax({

                    error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    },
                    url:"quizajax.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { 
                        quizidvalue: <?=$thisquizid?>
                    },


            }).done(function(data) {
                    questions = data;
                    for(i in data){
                        console.log(data[i]);

                    }
                });


        $("#nextquestionbtn").click(function () {
            nextQuestion();
        });
    });

function nextQuestion (){
    for(i in questions) {
        if(i<=currentquestion)
            continue;

        currentquestion = i;


        for(y in questions[i]) {
            console.log("CurrentA: "+ currentquestion);
            console.log("I: " + i);
            console.log(questions[i][y].answerid);
        }


        console.log("CurrentQ: "+ currentquestion);
        console.log("I: " + i);
        console.log(questions[i]);

        questionVariables ();


        break;
    }
```

And here is a question with it's records in my database

```
questionid | quizid | questiontype | qdescription | qfilelocation | noofanswers | answertype | answerid | adescription | afilelocation | iscorrect 
------------+--------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      795 | sadfds       | null          | t
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      796 | asdfsd       | null          | f
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      797 | asfsadf      | null          | f
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      798 | asdfsadf     | null          | f
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      799 | asdfsadf     | null          | f
        295 |     57 | text         | 6mark work   | null          |           6 | text       |      800 | sadfasdf     | null          | f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing row is coming from a logic error in the PHP.

In line 4 of your example `$questionrows = pg_fetch_array($questionquery);`, you're calling pg_num_rows(). This fetches the first row, which you are then ignoring because of the test condition of your `while` loop `while($row = pg_fetch_array($questionquery))` which again fetches the next row of the dataset.

Since it appears there is no need for any row contents prior to the loop, I'd suggest commenting, or removing, line 4.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php - I did not see information about fetching data on pg_num_rows

Comment: Correction: he's calling pg_fetch_array on line 4, not pg_num_rows.

Comment: Commented this out, you're correct it was unnecessary, however  the problem still occurs.

Comment: As of your edit,it works perfectly! Thank you very much Christopher